# some incompatible instantion of Props

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Why does this not work:

[Try Flow!](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCWBbADrATgF1AFSgCGAzqAEoCmxAxvpNrGqAOTY32sDcykArgDt6KWINBoq2AOZUAKgAsqkgDwAFJhlIAuUAG8AvgBpQc3YYB8ACkSg7oAMLMsgqoNy7qdXADonmMTdcOQBPDCoVPVBcJUldOVADUAAyUA1YLQsjW3sUQQArKnoqABNFZSp4xABKT05ffxcg0PDI6NjK00SUtM1SC30cu1oxUnxyyRLQAF5QKww+83aK+O7U9K1qmYG9Ifs7aCp8GJWu2bzC4rKO3n39jlx+bHEVRsD3fR8vhYzSJJPJNM9ACqElgBZbvYDJC7A8nuIJqVeAZkEA)

```
function mergeTheme<Props: {}, T: {}>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<{ theme: T } & Props>,
  injectedTheme: T
): React.ComponentType<{ theme: T } & Props> {
  const Themed = (props: { theme: T } & Props) => {
      let theme: T = injectedTheme;
      return <Component {...props} theme={theme} />;
  };
  return Themed;
}
```

The error:

```
11:         return <Component {...props} theme={theme} />;
                   ^ props of React element `Component`. This type is incompatible with
5: function mergeTheme<Props: {}, T: {}>(
   ^ some incompatible instantiation of `Props`
11:         return <Component {...props} theme={theme} />;
                   ^ props of React element `Component`. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
5: function mergeTheme<Props: {}, T: {}>(
   ^ some incompatible instantiation of `Props`
```

But this works:

[Try Flow!](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCWBbADrATgF1AFSgCGAzqAEoCmxAxvpNrGqAOTY32sDcykArgDt6KWINBoq2AOZUAKgAsqkgDwAFJhlIAuUAG8AvgBpQc3YYB8ACkSg7oAMLMsgqoNy7qdXADonmMTdcOQBPDCoVPVBcJUldOVADUAAyUA1YLQsjW3sUQQArKnoqABNFZSp4xABKT05ffxcg0PDI6NjK00SUtM1SC30cu1oxUnxyyRLQAF5QKww+83aK+O7U9K1qmYG9RABIPZHBMdAAIzIqDZ1ejPJZhdvee2fQaCp8GJWu2bzC4rKOk8XnYOLh+NhxCpGoF3PofPDzqRLn0kp9JNM9GiqElgBYgXYDPjQKDweIJqVeAZkEA)

```
function mergeTheme<Props: {}, T: {}>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<{ theme: T } & Props>,
  injectedTheme: T
): React.ComponentType<{ theme: T } & Props> {
  const Themed = (props: { theme: T } & Props) => {
      const baseProps: Props = props;
      let theme: T = injectedTheme;
      return <Component {...props} theme={theme} />;
  };
  return Themed;
}
```

What's the difference between the two? How do I get the first one to work?

Comment: so from what I gather looking at other flow issues, is that `Props` from the passed-in Component gets inferred as a separate type than the HOC's `Props` type and the only actual thing determined from the types is that both of those `Props` are just of type `{}`. They are not actually equal. Changing the parameter to: `Component: React.ComponentType<{ theme: T } & $Supertype<Props>>,` fixes the issue but I'm not sure if it's the correct approach

Comment: so it isn't the correct approach. Adding `$Supertype` seems to not catch missing props when consuming